# DavLockDB: what do we need it for?

Tags: apache, webdav

I configured a `webDAV` to be able to upload files onto server. All is well, but what exactly does the `DavLockDB` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache stores locking information when calling `LOCK`, and `UNLOCK` in the file specified in this configuration setting.